# Openswan High Availablity

Tags: vpn, cluster

I have configured hardware(juniper) to software VPN(openswan) tunnel. I want to make openswan highly available. I was wondering if i can configure openswan cluster, but I didn't find anything substantial regarding that. Can someone please help me on how should i make my openswan highly available so that if one node goes down, the second node would be available.

Answer (score 0):

I do this in a number of places, using Linux-HA which in turn uses crm to manage a shared IP address (which would be used by the juniper box as the endpoint), and to ensure that the `ipsec` service is only running on the current primary node.